# Changing words on a sentence to special characters

Tags: python

I am trying to change some words in a sentence to special characters but I don't get the required output. Also i have tried using the replace method which doesn't seen to replace everything but  only  the first word.

```
new_sentence = ''
sentence = input('Enter your word:')

for char in sentence:
    if 'the' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '~'
    elif 'as' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '^'
    elif 'and' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '+'
    elif 'that' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '$'
    elif 'must' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '&'
    elif 'Well those' in sentence:
        new_sentence += '% #'
    else:
        new_sentence += sentence 
print(new_sentence)
```

This is what happens when i run it.

```
Enter your word:the as much and
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Are you sure you did the replace method right?

Comment: If your sentence contains "The", then only your first conditional will trigger, and the rest won't, but it will still loop over all of the characters in the input string and trigger your first condition for each character

Comment: First, you're looping through the chars, what seems weird, as it'll loop through each individual letters, so t, h, e, etc...
If you'd like to loop through all words, first use `sentence.strip()` in order to generate a list with all the words, so just use `for word in sentence.strip()` for having the results you want, @daliseiy

Comment: You would want `sentence.split()` not `.strip()`, but that still would be highly inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store your character modifications in a dictionary and then apply them using `replace()` in a for loop, like so:

```
sentence = 'This is the sentence that I will modify with special characters and such'

modifiers = {'the': '~', 'as': '^', 'and': '+', 'that': '$', 'must': '&', 'Well those': '% #'}

for i, v in modifiers.items():
    sentence = sentence.replace(i, v)
```

Returns:

```
This is ~ sentence $ I will modify with special characters + such
```

Answer (score 1):

@rahlf23 has the right method, but just in case you wanted to work with your current implementation:

If you split the sentence into individual words, then iterate over those and check what the word itself is, instead of checking each character in the input string and checking whether any of the words to replace exist in the string, you'll be on the right track

```
for word in sentence.split():
    if word.lower() == 'the':
    new_sentence += '~'
    ...
```